# wso2 OAuth2Filter : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 302 Error: Found

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, access-token, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to protect my web application with OAuthFilter in wso2is-5.1.0, I am following this link from github https://github.com/sagara-gunathunga/oauth-filter, my code is running fine and it is protected. But when I am accessing my app with access token it's giving error

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 302 Error: Found     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:228)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.stub.OAuth2TokenValidationServiceStub.validate(OAuth2TokenValidationServiceStub.java:184)
>     at
>   com.bizruntime.idgen.TokenValidationClient.validateToken(TokenValidationClient.java:49)
>     at com.bizruntime.idgen.OAuth2Filter.doFilter(OAuth2Filter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

Comment: Can you see any error logs in Identity Server side ? Can you enable debug logs by putting this entry in log4j.properties file log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2=DEBUG

Comment: thanks for response, this message getting in wso2is console- No AuthorizationGrantCache entry found for the access token:1150175d60aca2585c6906f6dfc5c6e9, hence adding to cache

Comment: I am also getting this error in tomcat server,  **Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://localhost:9443/servicesOAuth2TokenValidationService]**

Comment: You might get this message in token generation "No AuthorizationGrantCache entry found for the access token:1150175d60aca2585c6906f6dfc5c6e9, hence adding to cache". Can you see any other error while validating access token ?